# How to prove the Cofactor Expansion Theorem for Determinant of a Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I understand that the definition of a determinant of  a matrix implies that you can expand over the first row over the matrix, but how does that itself imply that you can expand over *any* row the matrix. Is there a proper proof to this, perhaps using induction on the size of matrix or something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What definition of determinant are you working with and what preliminaries do you have? In case you have proven that the space of determinant functions is one-dimensional, a rather slick proof can be given.

Comment: The definition I've been given is as follows:  $det(A) = a_{11}(-1)^{1+1}det(A_{11}) + ... + a_{1k}(-1)^{1+k}det(A_{1k})$ where $A$ is a $k$ by $k$ square matrix and $A_{1i}$ is the submatrix of A from deleting the first row and $i$th column.

Comment: @Thorgott -- I know it's been a while, but if you don't mind, could you link the 'slick' proof?

Comment: @obr I don't have a reference at hand, but the proof I had in mind is simply to prove that the cofactor expansion is a multilinear, alternating function on square matrices taking the value $1$ on the identity matrix. The only such function is the usual determinant function, by the result that I mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a proof I found [here](http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-DM.html). The idea is to do induction: since the minors are smaller matrices, one can calculate them via the desired row/column.

One first checks by hand that the determinant can be calculated along any row when $n=1$ and $n=2$.
$\newcommand\detname{\,\det}$
$\newcommand\matrixentry[2]{#1_{#2}}$
$\newcommand\submatrix[3]{#1(#2|#3)}$

For the induction, we use the notation $\submatrix{A}{i_1,i_2}{j_1,j_2}$ to denote the $(n-2)\times (n-2)$ matrix obtained from $A$ by removing the rows $i_1$ and $i_2$, and the columns $j_1$ and $j_2$. We assume as inductive hypothesis that for square matrices with $n-1$ rows or less, the determinant can be calculated along any row/column.

For the calculation of the minors there will be a column missing when we express the minor in terms of the entries of the original matrix, so one needs to be careful with the signs. For that we use
$$
\epsilon_{\ell j}=\begin{cases} 0,&\ \ell <j \\ 1,&\ \ell>j\end{cases}
$$
As mentioned above, the idea is that one calculates the minors along the $i^{\rm th}$ row, which is ok by inductive hypothesis. We assume $i>1$, as we are comparing with calculating along the first row. The inductive hypothesis is used below in the second and last equalities.

\begin{align*}
\detname{A}
&=
\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{1+j}\matrixentry{A}{1j}\detname{\submatrix{A}{1}{j}}
\\
&=
\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{1+j}\matrixentry{A}{1j}
\sum_{\substack{1\leq\ell\leq n\\\ell\neq j}}
(-1)^{i-1+\ell-\epsilon_{\ell j}}\matrixentry{A}{i\ell}\detname{\submatrix{A}{1,i}{j,\ell}}
\\
&=
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{\substack{1\leq\ell\leq n\\\ell\neq j}}
(-1)^{j+i+\ell-\epsilon_{\ell j}}
\matrixentry{A}{1j}\matrixentry{A}{i\ell}\detname{\submatrix{A}{1,i}{j,\ell}}
\\
&=
\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}\sum_{\substack{1\leq j\leq n\\j\neq\ell}}
(-1)^{j+i+\ell-\epsilon_{\ell j}}
\matrixentry{A}{1j}\matrixentry{A}{i\ell}\detname{\submatrix{A}{1,i}{j,\ell}}
\\
&=
\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}(-1)^{i+\ell}\matrixentry{A}{i\ell}
\sum_{\substack{1\leq j\leq n\\j\neq\ell}}
(-1)^{j-\epsilon_{\ell j}}
\matrixentry{A}{1j}\detname{\submatrix{A}{1,i}{j,\ell}}
\\
&=
\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}(-1)^{i+\ell}\matrixentry{A}{i\ell}
\sum_{\substack{1\leq j\leq n\\j\neq\ell}}
(-1)^{\epsilon_{\ell j}+j}
\matrixentry{A}{1j}\detname{\submatrix{A}{i,1}{\ell,j}}
\\
&=
\sum_{\ell=1}^{n}(-1)^{i+\ell}\matrixentry{A}{i\ell}\detname{\submatrix{A}{i}{\ell}}
\end{align*}

Comment: I know this answer was posted a while ago, but I am unable to understand how $\det A(1|j) = \sum_{1 \leq l \leq n} (-1)^{i - 1 + l - \varepsilon_{lj}}A_{il} \det A(1,i|j,l)$. I understand the $\det A(1,i|j,l)$ part, but the rest I'm am unable to. When I expand $\det A(1|j)$, I get $\sum_{1 \leq l \leq n} (-1)^{i + l} [A(1 | j)]_{il} \det A(1, i|j, l)$. If you don't mind could you help me explain this? The link wasn't of much help either. Thanks!

Comment: You are writing the sum from $1$ to $n$, but you have to omit $i$. Also, you want to write the entries of $A(1|j)$ in terms of the entries of $A$; that's where $A_{i\ell}$ comes from, and the indices  $i-1+\ell-\epsilon_{\ell j}$ account for the shifting of the signs  that occurs as you omit row $i$.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but what you mean by "omit $i$"? Also, I understand that we want to write the entries of $A(1|j)$ in terms of $A$, but it isn't clear to me how $[A(1|j)]_{il} = A_{il}$. From what I can tell, when $l < j$, we have $[A(1|j)]_{il} = A_{(i+1)l}$ and when $l > j$, we have $[A(1|j)]_{il} = A_{(i+1)(l+1)}$.

Comment: But I'm indexing $j$ from $1$ to $n$ (and omitting $i$).

Comment: Forgive my thickness, but I'm still struggling to understand the entire expression.

Comment: Nothing to apologize for. I need to go carefully though the formula to check there is nothing wrong; I'll do it when I have some time available. On a first look it seems that I wrote things slightly simpler than they should have been, but like I said I need to check it carefully when I have a bit of time.

Comment: @obround: my apologies that it took me a year to come back to this. I have checked the computation again and it looks sound to me. In the odd case that you are still interested and have questions about it, let me know.